# random number added to ajax requests

Tags: jquery, asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc-4

I am working with asp.net mvc and jquery. I am calling controller actions from jquery by using

```
$.getJSON("/customer/details", function (data) {
       // process the data
    });
```

I have output cache set up on my controller action but its not working as it seems that the cache is getting busted as the url contains a random number eg.

```
https://localhost/customer/details?_=1403629723467
```

This is not being populated by me but by the framework. Any way I can stop this being added to the ur?

Answer (score 4):

That's because of `cache: false`. That prevents the browser from fetching content from it's cache and is used for `GET` & `HEAD` requests.

You can confirm -- but for obvious reasons I would not advise to leave the setting on - you can turn it off and you won't see the number:

```
$.ajaxSetup({cache:true});
```

> *cache (default: true, false for dataType 'script' and 'jsonp')* **Type:
>   Boolean** If set to false, it will force requested pages not to be
>   cached by the browser. Note: Setting cache to false will only work
>   correctly with HEAD and GET requests. It works by appending
>   **"_={timestamp}"** to the GET parameters. The parameter is not needed for
>   other types of requests, except in IE8 when a POST is made to a URL
>   that has already been requested by a GET.

Reference:

```
- http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/
```